# I need to slow down my espresso test case run

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using espresso 2.2.1 for android testing. I am running few test cases and some are failing because espresso is running too fast. Elements are not even loaded to display and thats why test cases are failing. Is there any way to slow down these runs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create specific matcher which will wait for view with id or view with text or whatever:

```
public static ViewAction waitViewWithMatcher(Func1<View, Boolean> predicate, final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for a specific during " + millis + " millis.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + millis;

            do {
                for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    if (predicate.call(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(EspressoTestUtil.waitViewWithMatcher(v -> withId(R.id.view_id).matches(v), 30000));
```

It waits for view with id `view_id`, 30000 ms.

Comment: predicate.call(child) and Func1<View, Boolean> predicate are giving errors. is there any dependency needs to be added or is there any specific definition of these 2 ?

Comment: ah yes sorry. It's from rxjava. You can just copy-paste it - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.0.13/rx/functions/Func1.java#Func1 in your project.

Comment: uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50) this method will loop main thread for 50 mili seconds right ?

Comment: Yes, method of name is quite self explaining.